# Как сделать открытие меню при одному клике?

Tags: javascript, меню

Доброго дня. Есть скрипт:

```
function openbox(id){
    display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

    if(display=='none'){
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
    }else{
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Сама менюшка

```
    <div class="h_menu">
        <div class="h_menu_list" onclick="openbox('h_menu');"><p>Меню</p></div>
        <div class="m_container"  id="h_menu">
            <?php wp_nav_menu (array('theme_location' => 'menu') ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Открывает и закрывает меню при нажатии на кнопку, но, при первом открытии открывает меню лишь после двух кликов. Меню изначально скрыто (дисплей нон). Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы меню присваивался дисплей блок сразу же при клике, а при повторном клике дисплей нон?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/0m2ngcot/

Comment: Ваша ошибка не воспроизводится. Меню открывается с первого раза.

Comment: Тогда не пойму.. У меня на компьютере и на телефоне приходиться дважды кликать, чтобы открыть.

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://jsfiddle.net/0m2ngcot/1/

Comment: Я хз, но, вообще нифига не работает...

Answer (score 0):

Вроде, все работает...:

```js
function openbox(id) {
  let display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

  if (display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="h_menu">
  <div class="h_menu_list" onclick="openbox('h_menu');">
    <p>Меню</p>
  </div>
  <div class="m_container" id="h_menu" style="display:none;">
    <div>11111111</div>
    <div>2222222222</div>
    <div>33333333</div>
    <div>4444444444</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно, но, совсем перестало работать.. хотя тут работает. Прикрепил сверху меню.

Comment: @NikitaTitorovich все равно...

Comment: Хоть убей, реально, все как у тебя вставил, не работает...